# Javascript strToLower(), uft8 and (german) special characters

Tags: javascript, utf-8, lowercase

i am running into trouble with JavaScripts strToLower()

```
var s = 'tür';
alert(s);
alert(s.strToLower());
```

should result in the same output. however the output is different:

```
1: tÃ¼r
2: tã¼r
```

any suggestions how to handle the uft8-special correctly if using strToLower()?

Martin

Comment: JavaScript has no `strToLower` function. PHP does, and a quick search reveals at least one person has ported it to JavaScript for some reason, but JavaScript itself doesn't have one. The JavaScript function, `toLowerCase`, [doesn't seem to exhibit the behavior you mention](http://jsbin.com/epefab) on Chrome, Firefox, or Opera on Linux or on IE9 or Safari on Windows 7.

Comment: Your page is encoded as utf8, but your server wrongly tells it's ISO-8859-1. Fix your headers.

Comment: Flagged as Too Localized -- given that JavaScript doesn't have this function and you haven't responded to comments, it's impossible for anyone to say what's going on here.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript's native `.toLowerCase()` method handles UTF-8 just fine:

```
alert( "tür".toLowerCase() );
```

Your page encoding might need to be set to UTF-8 with a header or `meta`-tag.

Comment: are you tried that ?  alert( "İbranice, IRMAK".toLowerCase() ); --JS's native doesn't support utf-8 completely

Comment: Depends on the browser & OS, but your example works as intended: "Most Unicode software [...] unless specifically set up for Turkish, it lowercases I to i and uppercases i to I. Thus uppercasing then lowercasing, or vice versa, changes the letters." [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted\_and\_dotless\_I)

Answer (score 0):

There is a toLowerCase function and it should work ok as Javascript uses UTF8 internally. Check:

http://jsfiddle.net/5k5hv/

Answer (score 0):

You have two built-in functions to convert to lowercase: [.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) and [.toLocaleLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase). Both should work just fine with the example you provide, but you need to make sure you've saved your source code as UTF-8. The exact procedure heavily depends  on your IDE or editor.

Additionally, it won't hurt if your web server appends the charset to Content-Type headers.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file you are working with is encoded into "UTF-8 without BOM" (option in Notepad++) and add `<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=EUC-JP">` inside `<head>`

I tried and works.

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes no sense. If you assign `tür` to a string, then you will always get `tür` back. You are probably omitting a step from your code, such as sending the string over AJAX to a server. To do this, the string will have to be encoded, usually using UTF-8, in which case the correct encoding is `tÃ¼r` as you observed. However if the server is working in ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8 then it will think that you original string was `tÃ¼r` and will attempt to lowercase it to `tã¼r` as described. This will cause problems when the front end tries to interpret it as UTF-8. The solution is to ensure that the server is also working in UTF-8.