# convert all type of languages to one for comparison

Tags: javascript, string, search

I have a search text input, I use this script for search, the function I use for standardize string is `str.toLowerCase`. It 's worked perfectly for English statement. but in my case there is other languages like Arabic and Persian.

In this situation my search function does not work correct.  How can I Convert all string to one type of something that I can use it for compare strings.

**search function:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myInput').on('keyup', function () {

        var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase(); //<--------------

        $('#areas_list>option').each(function(){

            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase(); // <---------

            for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
                if (text.search(valThis) > 0) {
                    $(this).show();
                }else if (!valThis) {
                    $(this).show();
                }else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9990899/javascript-strtolower-uft8-and-german-special-characters

Answer (score 1):

> I use this script for search, the function I use for standardize
>   string is str.toLowerCase. It 's worked perfectly for English
>   statement. but in my case there is other languages like Arabic and
>   Persian.

You can use [toLocaleLowerCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase)

```
var valThis = $(this).val().toLocaleLowerCase();
```

As per doc

> The default locale is the host environment’s current locale.

Please note that

- You need to pass the locale if your system's locale is not the locale of the data.

Comment: It may be that for `toLocaleLowerCase()` the page must be saved as UTF8 and the webserver also adds this to the http headers.

Comment: @OlafW If OP hasn't done the *UTF-8* settings, then OP wouldn't be able to see the utf-8 characters on the web-page at first place.

Comment: @MasterYoda System's locale is default locale. If not, then locale(s) has to be passed.

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work again. there is a weird thing search does not show results for `17` in both `str.toLowerCase()` and `str.toLocaleLowerCase()`  any idea?

Comment: @MasoudTavakkoli Can you please make a snippet or a fiddle so that your issue can be replicated and be used for debugging?